# Бот думает что команды не существует

Tags: python, бот, discord

Писал код для дискорд бота. Суть такая: на команду /quest у меня стоит кулдаун в 1 час (3600 секунд). У меня есть команда, которую надо вводить по сути так: /reset_cd quest
Но когда я пишу эту команду в дискорде, мне пишет, что команда quest не найдена. Пробовал писать и /reset_cd /quest но всё равно ничего не получается. В интернете смотрел способы решения, но ничего. Команда зарегистрирована, даже в консоли никаких ошибок. Просто команда не найдена.

Команда /quest:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Реши пример и получи 10 тысяч денег!')
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def quest(interaction):
    user_wallet = await get_user_wallet(interaction.author.id)
    
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10000)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 7000)
    
    expression = f"{num1} + {num2}"
    result = num1 + num2
    
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Решите пример: **{expression}**")
    
    try:    
        def check(m):
            return m.author == interaction.author and m.channel == interaction.channel
        
        print(result)

        user_answer = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=5, check=check)
        
        if user_answer.content.isdigit() and int(user_answer.content) == result:
            user_wallet["balance"] += 10000
            set_user_wallet(interaction.author.id, "balance", user_wallet["balance"])
            await interaction.followup.send(f"**Правильно! Вы заработали 10 000 денег!**")
        else:
            await interaction.followup.send(f"**Неправильно. Попробуйте ещё раз позже.**")
    
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await interaction.followup.send("**Время на решение примера истекло. Попробуйте ещё раз.**")
```

Команда /reset_cd:

```
@bot.slash_command()
@commands.check(lambda ctx: ctx.author.id == 1111894234216288328)
async def reset_cd(interaction, command_name: str):
    """Сбросить кд для команды

    Parameters
    -----------
    command_name: str
        Какой команде снять кд?
    """
    await bot.wait_until_ready()  # Дождитесь, пока бот полностью загрузится и зарегистрирует все команды

    command = bot.get_command(command_name)
    if command:
        command.reset_cooldown(ctx)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Кд для команды {command_name} сброшен.")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Команда {command_name} не найдена.")
```

Помогите пожалуйста, если вдруг у меня неправильный код!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, проблема в том, что вы используете в строке **ctx**, которого там (если я не ошибаюсь) быть не может:

> command.reset_cooldown(ctx)

Измените её и передайте в этот параметр **interaction**:

> command.reset_cooldown(interaction)

Comment: Вообще, я бы посоветовал вам использовать базы данных (даже json файл) для установки кд команде, т.к. при перезагрузке бота все кд слетают и смысла, получается, от него нет.